# GitHub-like punchcard with the help of pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

Is it possible to create a punchcard so it will look like the same on [GitHub](https://github.com/m0nhawk/leechcraft/graphs/punch-card) with the help of `pgfplots`?

The data stored in `punchcard.dat`:

```
0 Monday 18
1 Monday 67
2 Monday 62
<hour> <day> <commits>
```

Comment: You can not award yourself a bounty, according to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54998/i-just-awarded-myself-a-bounty/97802#97802

Comment: Oh, they already fix this...

Answer (score 30, accepted):

First I let's take a good color for showing impact:

```
\definecolor{skyblue}{rgb}{0.447,0.624,0.812}
```

Skyblue color! Cool looking and just nice. There is no problem for including `pgfplots` and give it some options:

```
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}
```

And the most interesting part:

- first (lines `1` and `2`) we open `axis` environment;
- on lines `3-7` we define some general options;
- `9-11`: let opacity be `50 * commits / 1000 + 50`;
- `12-13`: defining size of mark as `6.5 * commits / 1000 + 1`;
- on lines `14-18` we change size, color and filling of mark.

Finally:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\definecolor{skyblue}{rgb}{0.447,0.624,0.812}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}                                             %1
        \begin{axis}[                                               %2
                grid=major,                                         %3
                point meta=explicit,
                xmin=-1,
                xmax=24,
                xlabel=Hours,                                       %7
                scatter/@pre marker code/.code={
                    \pgfmathparse{                                  %9
                        \pgfplotspointmetatransformed/1000*50+50}   %10
                    \let\opacity=\pgfmathresult                     %11
                    \pgfmathparse{                                  %12
                        \pgfplotspointmetatransformed/1000*6.5+1}   %13
                    \def\markopts{                                  %14
                        mark=*,                                     %15
                        color=skyblue!\opacity,                     %16
                        fill=skyblue!\opacity,                      %17
                        mark size=\pgfmathresult}                   %18
                    \expandafter\scope\expandafter[\markopts]},
                scatter/@post marker code/.code={
                    \endscope},
                symbolic y coords={Sunday,Saturday,Friday,Thursday,Wednesday,Tuesday,Monday},
                xtick={0,...,23},
                x=0.6cm,
                y=0.6cm]
            \addplot[only marks,scatter]
                table[x index=0, y index=1, meta index=2] {punchcard.dat};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And the result:

[image]

Comment: Looks great! Minor detail : If `pgfplots` developer(s) decide to change something in later versions and you keep `compat=newest` all the time, the code would break down. Just use the version that you have successfully implemented and it would be OK.

Comment: @percusse Thanks! Never though of `compat=` in that way!

Comment: At first I was amazed at how quickly this answer came up! Then I realized you posted the question too :) Nice work :)

Comment: Nice solution! Note that in case you need *two* input parameters in your table instead of just `\pgfplotspointmetatransformed`, you could use `visualization depends on`. That, however, would not be mapped automatically.