# 2D correlation plot matrix with shapes

Tags: pgfplots, matrices, plot, r

Is there a straightforward way to create a correlation plot matrix similar to the figure below?

[image: R corrplot with circle method]

The image is an example of R's `corrplot` [package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/corrplot/vignettes/corrplot-intro.html) using circles, which also offers other shapes and colour schemes to draw these plots. Ideally I'd like to do this with tikz/pgfplots.

An example of the kind of data I want to plot in a table format. The first two columns are the X and Y labels, the third contains the values (which, for example, would be represented as the circles' radii):

```
X   Y   value

0.7 0   0.80
1.5 0   0.80
3.8 0   0.80
9.9 0   0.80
19.7    0   0.80

0.7 1   0.61
1.5 1   0.61
3.8 1   0.64
9.9 1   0.62
19.7    1   0.61

0.7 2   0.53
1.5 2   0.54
3.8 2   0.57
9.9 2   0.53
19.7    2   0.52

0.7 5   0.52
1.5 5   0.52
3.8 5   0.55
9.9 5   0.49
19.7    5   0.49

0.7 10  0.52
1.5 10  0.53
3.8 10  0.56
9.9 10  0.50
19.7    10  0.50
```

Comment: What does your input data look like? Do you have a table of pre-calculated correlation coefficients (then it's easy), or do you want PGFPlots to calculate the coefficients (much harder and slower)?

Comment: The data is already calculated.

Comment: Could you include a sample of what your data format looks like (is it a matrix or a list)?

Comment: I've edited the question to include it.

Comment: Here is another related way to present a matrix-data diagram: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135892/any-package-for-matrix-diagram

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a way to achieve this:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colorbrewer}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis equal image, % We want a square grid, not a rectangular one
    scatter, % This activates the color mapping
    colormap/viridis, % Choose the colormap
    colorbar, % Add a legend
    point meta min=0,
    point meta max=1,
    grid=minor, % Grid lines between the intervals
    minor tick num=1, % One minor tick per interval
    tickwidth=0pt, % Don't draw the major tick marks
    y dir=reverse, % Y increases downward
    xticklabel pos=right, % X axis labels go to the top
    enlargelimits={abs=0.5}, % Add half a unit on all sides
    scatter/@pre marker code/.append code={% A bit of magic for scaling the circles in axis units
      \pgfplotstransformcoordinatex{sqrt(abs(\pgfplotspointmeta))}% Area scales with the square of the radius
      \scope[mark size=\pgfplotsunitxlength*\pgfmathresult/2, fill=mapped color]
    },
    scatter/@post marker code/.append code={%
      \endscope%
    }
]
\addplot +[
    point meta=explicit, % We'll provide values for the color and size
    only marks, % No lines between the points
    ] table [
    x expr={int(mod(\coordindex+0.01,5))}, % The position depends on the coordinate index, not the X or Y values
    y expr={int((\coordindex+0.01)/5))},
    meta=value
] {
X   Y   value

0.7 0   0.80
1.5 0   0.80
3.8 0   0.80
9.9 0   0.5
19.7    0   0.08

0.7 1   0.61
1.5 1   0.61
3.8 1   0.64
9.9 1   0.62
19.7    1   0.61

0.7 2   0.53
1.5 2   0.54
3.8 2   0.57
9.9 2   0.53
19.7    2   0.52

0.7 5   0.52
1.5 5   0.52
3.8 5   0.55
9.9 5   0.49
19.7    5   0.49

0.7 10  0.52
1.5 10  0.53
3.8 10  0.56
9.9 10  0.50
19.7    10  0.50
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That looks very nice! I'd have to do a bit of tweaking to get the labels to show the coordinates in the data while not modifying the positions, but otherwise it seems straightforward. Thanks!

Comment: @Jake: I really like your Heatmap. I managed to adapt it to a 3x3 design but would also like to use it with a 4x8 layout. Could you please provide an explanation or example? I am not fully grasping the coordindex. Thanks!!

Comment: I would really appreciate your help :)

Comment: @poebelchen Sorry for the lack of response. I don't have a working LaTeX installation, so I can't help at the moment. I think your best bet is to post a new question referencing this answer.