# small 3x3 matrix/picture/table with dots

Tags: tables, diagrams

I want to create some sort of arrangement of small(!) dots (some filled, some not) in a 3x3 shape like this

[image: picture]

Has anyone an idea how to do this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Not clear what exactly you want, but here are some for consideration: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/390466/drawing-grids-with-different-colors, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135892/any-package-for-matrix-diagram, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/308936/what-is-the-best-way-to-create-this-kind-of-binary-matrix, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/157080/can-tikz-create-pixel-art-images

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{matrix}
\circ & \bullet & \circ \\
\bullet & \bullet & \bullet \\
\circ & \bullet & \circ 
\end{matrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Starting with Ignasi's core, but using `tabstackengine` instead of `matrix` allows for the spacing to be tightly controlled and tailored.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\TABstackMath
\begin{document}
\[
\setstacktabbedgap{\Sstackgap}
\def\grid{\tabbedShortstack{
\circ & \bullet & \circ \\
\bullet & \bullet & \bullet \\
\circ & \bullet & \circ 
}}
\setstackgap{S}{7pt}\grid\qquad
\setstackgap{S}{4pt}\grid\qquad
\setstackgap{S}{1pt}\grid\qquad
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]