# How to draw a punchcard in Latex

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, charts

I would like to draw a punchcard in Latex as shown below. 
But i just can't find any information how to do this (not even in the manual of tikz). The only thing i can find is information about bubble charts (with x and y axis)
I would like to get the data from a csv-file, for example with the command:

```
\addplot table {table.csv}
```

Link to my data as .ods-file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/3qgdh9klo2xpxcz/punchcard.ods

as csv-file (without headers): https://www.dropbox.com/s/10ql1wzf8ired9p/punchcard-csv.csv

[image: punchard]

Source of that image is the article of Maalej and Robillard: Patterns of knowledge in API reference documentation

Comment: First, do you have this data? Second, this is named a ["punchcard"](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/86115/9790) and I once post helpful answer for you. I can adjust it for you, if you share the data.

Comment: Just for curiousity: what is the meaning of the different sizes and colors?

Comment: the different sizes are for different absolute values (like 1 is small and 100 is big). In this example black points are for positive values and gray are for negative ones.

Comment: @m0nhawk still willing to help me out? :)

Comment: Where is the command `\addplot` defined? Also, rather than giving a link to a dropbox folder it would be more helpful if you showed us the first few lines of the data file. Also, please consider adding a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Comment: @sv0101 I'm looking into `pgfplots` and can it use this format. Looks like not...

Comment: You can take some ideas from: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20496/1952, http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/164995/1952 and linked questions there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a workaround you can use my [old code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/86115/9790) with a [converted data](http://sharesend.com/qpuadco0):

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\definecolor{skyblue}{rgb}{0.447,0.624,0.812}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
                grid=major,
                point meta=explicit,
                scatter/@pre marker code/.code={
                    \pgfmathparse{
                        \pgfplotspointmetatransformed/1000*50+50}
                    \let\opacity=\pgfmathresult
                    \pgfmathparse{
                        \pgfplotspointmetatransformed/1000*6.5+1}
                    \def\markopts{
                        mark=*,
                        color=skyblue!\opacity,
                        fill=skyblue!\opacity,
                        mark size=\pgfmathresult}
                    \expandafter\scope\expandafter[\markopts]},
                scatter/@post marker code/.code={
                    \endscope},
                symbolic x coords={Type2,Type3,Type4,Type5,Type6,Type7,Type8,Type9,Type10,Type11,Type12},
                symbolic y coords={Type12,Type11,Type10,Type9,Type8,Type7,Type6,Type5,Type4,Type3,Type2,Type1}]
            \addplot[only marks,scatter]
                table[x index=0, y index=1, meta index=2] {punchcard.csv};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @sv0101 But you need to completely rework your data.

Comment: I saw. But that's a small problem to solve.

Comment: Y-Axis end now with Type10 (should be Type11) and x-Axis starts with Type3 (should be Type2). Is that also caused by the data or by settings?

Comment: By the data. I just remove the Type-Type with zero.

Comment: @sv0101 Oh, also I forget the `Type11 Type12 12`. Sorry for that, just add it and update.